# Source for the allowance of the throwing out hafrashas challah

Tags: sources-mekorot, separating-challah

In the Sefer Practical Guide to Kashruth page 101 notes that the proper disposal of the hafrashas challah is to burn it (brought in the Shulchan Aruch and Maharil). It then notes that when burning is impractical one may wrap it in paper or place it in a paper bag and put it away for disposal.

In footnote 32 it writes that this is the minhag in eretz yisrael based on the Chazon Ish. Does anyone know where the Chazon Ish writes that it is permissible to dispose of the challah instead of burning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this source quoted in multiple places (e.g., OU [here](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/halachos-of-hafrashas-challah/#fn88380163250cf4c73f2885), note 17) as the **Chazon Ish Zeraim Demai 15:1**.

See also R Doniel Neustadt noting in footnote 29 [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5761-vayera/) other *poskim* who agree.